# unsigned-signed underflow mechanism

Tags: c++, c

I know that the following

```
unsigned short b=-5u;
```

evaluates to b being 65531 due to an underflow, but I don't understand if 5u is converted to a signed int before being transformed into -5 and then re-converted back to unsigned to be stored in b or -5u is equal to 0 - 5u (this should not be the case, -x is a unary operator)

Comment: Unsigned integers *can't* overflow. What gets assigned is: `-5+USHRT_MAX+1`.

Comment: @KingsIndian What gets assigned is `-(unsigned)5`, converted to type `unsigned short`.  `-(unsigned)5` is the equivalent of `UINT_MAX+1-5`.

Comment: @JamesKanze You mean `USHRT_INT+1-5`, right?

Comment: @Actually: the equivalent of `-5 % (USHRT_INT + 1)`.  In the case of -5, it doesn't make a difference, but it's quite possible to have a results of `-(unsigned)5` for which `USHRT_MAX + 1 - X` would still not be representable on an `unsigned short`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`5u` is a literal unsigned integer, `-5u` is its negation..  Negation for unsigned integers is defined as subtraction from 2**n, which gets the same result as wrapping the result of subtraction from zero.

Comment: Unsigned arithmetic is defined as modulo arithmetic, congruent 2^n.  The effects for unary - are the same as you describe, but things like multiplication can result in different values.  (Just subtraction could still result in an out of range value.)

Comment: @JamesKanze It isn't just a description, the C++ Standard's definition of the operation is "the negative of an unsigned quantity is computed by subtracting its value from 2**n".  My comment about subtraction from zero was just addressing OP's consequence-free distinction between `0-5u` and `-5u`

Comment: Yes, but he doesn't take the negative of an unsigned short (and because of integral promotion, he can't).  Since he assigns the results to an `unsigned short`, there's a type conversion involved as well.  And of course, more generally: type conversions _to_ unsigned integral types, and all unsigned arithmetic in general, obeys the rules of modulo arithmetic, congruent 2^n.

Comment: That's all true, but it's not to the point -- he didn't ask about what happens during the conversion, he asked about what happens before the conversion.

Answer (score 3):

`5u` is a single token, an rvalue expression which has type `unsigned int`.
The unary `-` operator is applied to it according to the rules of unsigned
arithmetic (arithmetic modulo 2^n, where *n* is the number of bits in the
unsigned type).  The results are converted to `unsigned short`; if they don't
fit (and they won't if `sizeof(int) > sizeof(short)`), the conversion will
be done using modulo arithmetic as well (modulo 2^n, where *n* is the number of
bits in the target type).

It's probably worth noting that if the original argument has type `unsigned
short`, the actual steps are different (although the results will always be
the same).  Thus, if you'd have written:

```
unsigned short k = 5;
unsigned short b = -k;
```

the first operation would depend on the size of short.  If shorts are smaller
than ints (often, but not always the case), the first step would be to promote
`k` to an `int`.  (If the size of short and int are identical, then the first
step would be to promote `k` to `unsigned int`; from then on, everything
happens as above.)  The unary `-` would be applied to this `int`, according to
the rules of signed integer arithmetic (thus, resulting in a value of -5).  The
resulting -5 will be implicitly converted to `unsigned short`, using modulo
arithmetic, as above.

In general, these distinctions don't make a difference, but in cases where you
might have an integral value of `INT_MIN`, they could; on 2's complement
machines, `-i`, where `i` has type `int` and value `INT_MIN` is implementation
defined, and may result in strange values when later converted to unsigned.

Comment: @jogojapan Yes.  I mistyped.  I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1):

ISO/IEC 14882-2003 section 4.7 says:

"If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo 2^n where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type). [ Note: In a two’s complement representation, this conversion is conceptual and there is no change in the bit pattern (if there is no truncation). —end note ]

Answer (score 0):

Technically not an underflow, just the representation of the signed value `-5` when shown as an unsigned number. Note that signed and unsigned numbers have the same "bits" - they just display differently. If you were to print the value as a signed value [assuming it's extended using the sign bit to fill the remaining bits], it would show -5. [This assumes that it's a typical machine using 2s complement. The C standard doesn't require that `signed` and `unsigned` types are the same number of bits, nor that the computer uses 2s complement for representing signed numbers - obviously, if it's not using 2s complement, it won't match up to the value you've shown, so I made the assumption that yours IS a 2s complement machine - which is all common processors, such as x86, 68K, 6502, Z80, PDP-11, VAX, 29K, 8051, ARM, MIPS. But technically, it is not necessary for C to function correctly]

And when you use the unary operator `-x`, it has the same effect as `0-x` [this applies for computers as well as math - it has the same result].

Comment: First, there's actually no requirement (at least in C) that equivalent signed and unsigned types have the same number of bits, and there is at least one C implementation where they don't.  The only requirement is that `UINT_MAX >= INT_MAX`.  And signed and unsigned arithmetic obey different rules; enough so that you want to avoid unsigned types whenever arithmetic might occur.  (You seem to be assuming 2's complement and that signed arithmetic wraps.  Neither are true for all implementations.)

Comment: And I take it that you have worked on several machines with these features? I can certainly say I haven't. But I will edit the answer to reflect that "on a typical machine with 2s complement arithmetics..."

Comment: Not necessarily worked on them, but I am aware of their existence.  (I'm only aware of one modern machine where signed and unsigned have a different number of value bits---the hardware simply doesn't support unsigned, so the compiler simulates it by masking out the sign bit.)