# If I decrement `std::size_t(0)` is that guaranteed to be equal to `std::size_t(-1)`?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, integer-overflow, unsigned-integer

Here's evidence that it is:

```
inline
constexpr std::size_t prev(std::size_t i) {
    --i;
    return i;
}

int main() {
    static const std::size_t i = 0;
    static_assert(prev(i) == std::size_t(-1), "Decrementing should give     std::size_t(-1)");    
    return 0;
}
```

That compiles happily with `-std=c++14`.

I came upon this because I had a loop indexing over a `std::vector` and wanted to loop backward, so I changed it to

```
for (std::size_t i = std::min(idx, v.size() - 1); i != std::size_t(-1); --i) { ... }
```

Now, I realize I could use `std::vector::reverse_iterator`, but my real question now is, is the behavior I'm expecting well-defined?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9193880/1896169 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/18195715/1896169 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/16056758/1896169

Comment: @Justin Those are about unsigned integer *overflow*, not underflow that happens here.

Comment: Best dupe I have found so far: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15172936/unsigned-signed-underflow-mechanism

Comment: What about [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760502/question-about-c-behaviour-for-unsigned-integer-underflow)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this behavior is guaranteed.

[`std::size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) is an unsigned integer type. [Arithmetic on unsigned integers always has well defined semantics](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Overflows):

> Unsigned integer arithmetic is always performed modulo 2<sup>n</sup>
>   where n is the number of bits in that particular integer.

Specifically considering the built-in [pre-decrement and post-decrement operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec):

> [T]he expression `--x` is exactly equivalent to `x -= 1`. ... 
>   [T]he expression `x--` modifies the value of its operand as if by evaluating `x -= 1`

So the decrement operator *does* perform an arithmetic operation.

Comment: You get the green check because of the details on increment and decrement operators.

Answer (score 6):

## Yes

`size_t` is an unspecified unsigned integer.

All unsigned integers in C++ are modelled as elements of the ring of integers modulo 2<sup>n</sup> for some number n specific to that unsigned integer type.

When you convert a signed integer to an unsigned integer you get the value in the ring of integers modulo 2<sup>n</sup> for the constant n for that unsigned type.  For -1, this is 2<sup>n</sup>-1.

When you decrement 0 as an unsigned integer type, you get 2<sup>n</sup>-1.

These two values are the same.

See [basic.fundamental] 3.9.1/4 from the C++ standard:

> Unsigned integers shall obey the laws of arithmetic modulo
> 2<sup>n</sup>
> where
> n
> is the number of bits in the value
> representation of that particular size of integer.

(Quote taken from N3690, a recent draft standard, but the truth it represents isn't going to change any time soon; the paragraph number might.)

Finding quotes on how conversion from a signed integer works would involve more standard chasing; but it ends up being what you want.